# Set nested objects to null if IDs are null

Tags: java, mapstruct

I would like to configure mapstruct to set an object to null if his id is null. And/or to not initialize the object in the first instance if all his fields are null.

Right now I do this:

```
public void setNestedObjectsToNullIfIdsNull(Servicio entity) {
        if(entity == null) return;

        if(entity.getViaje() != null && entity.getViaje().getId() == null) {
            entity.setViaje(null);
        }
        if(entity.getPaciente() != null && entity.getPaciente().getId() == null) {
            entity.setPaciente(null);
        }
        //... this is bad
}
```

I do this because I can not insert the entity to database if this have relational objects initialized and their ids are null.

Comment: What is your question/what is not working?

Comment: @rileyjsumner I would like to configure mapstruct to set an object to null if his id is null, automatically. The issue now is that if I do it manually, the code is not maintanable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately this is a known limitation within MapStruct. The only way to achieve this is to use `@AfterMapping` and reset the objects to `null`.

There is already [this](https://github.com/mapstruct/mapstruct/issues/1166) request within the MapStruct issues that is looking for something similar.